# How to find the surface area of a region in a cylinder?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area

I want to find the surface area of a shape that is represented by the following two functions (at the same time):
$$z^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1,(z\lt0)$$
$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}\le1$$
Should I use the surface area equation$A=\int\int_R\sqrt{1+(g_x)^2+(g_y)^2}dA$? Or do I need to do something else? Please help me out!
Thank you.

Update:
So now I got the answer. Can anyone check if it's right?
The shape above can also be defined as the intersection between two cylinders$$z^2+\frac{y^2}{4}=1,(z\lt0)$$
$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$$
And $$z=-\sqrt{1-\frac{y^2}{4}}$$
$$g_x=0$$
$$g_y=-\frac12\times\left(1-\frac{y^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac12}\times2y\times\left(-\frac14\right)$$
$$=\frac14y\times\left(1-\frac{y^2}{4}\right)^{-\frac12}$$
$$A=\int\int_R\sqrt{1+(g_x)^2+(g_y)^2}dA$$
$$A=\int\int_R\sqrt{1+o+\frac{y^2}{16-4y^2}}dA$$
$$=\int\int_R\sqrt{\frac{16-3y^2}{16-4y^2}}dA$$
$$=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\frac32\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\frac32\sqrt{4-y^2}}\sqrt{\frac{16-3y^2}{16-4y^2}}dxdy$$
$$=\int_{-2}^23\sqrt{\frac{16-3y^2}{16-4y^2}}\times\sqrt{4-y^2}dy$$
$$=\int_{-2}^23\frac{\sqrt{16-3y^2}}{2}dy$$
$$=20.5(GDC,3SF)$$

Comment: The first eqn defines the mantle of an elliptiptical cylinder, while the second one defines a solid elliptical cylinder. How is your shape defined exactly?

Comment: I created the functions by myself so I'm not sure how it's supposed to be defined. The equations are supposed to represent a potato chip (Lays or something) as the intersection of the two equations above.

Comment: To @shiseiliu : Your approach seems correct, did you try to find the surface?

Comment: I don't know how to, as there are three variables but the surface area equation only need two variables. Should I try to represent y with x and z?